# Using a particular version of java in a specific directory

Tags: linux, bash, java

My current default version of Java is 7 (which, for now, can't be updated - I know it's reached EOL), but also have Java 8 installed.

However, I have some third party jars (all contained in a directory) that require Java 1.8. Each jar has an associated bash script to check relevant environment variables, and to construct the java command required to run the jar.  Each bash script assumes that the command to invoke java is, unsurprisingly, `java`.

Is there a way for me to change the version of java that is executed when `java` is invoked from 7 to 8 in *this folder only*?

Comment: [This SO answer is for Windows, the general idea is the same on Linux, I suggest you use the knowlege contained in it to achieve your goals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050538/how-to-run-a-specific-version-of-java-with-a-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure: add your `pwd` to your `PATH` variable, in the most significant position, *i.e.*,

```
 export PATH=.:$PATH
```

You should use the above version, **not** `export PATH=$PWD:$PATH` because in this case `$PWD` is evaluated at the time of sourcing the bash file containing the command, while you want it to be evaluated every time.

Now create a symbolic to the java version you want to use, in the directory where you need this to differ from the standard version:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java ./java
```

or whatever your executable is called.

Notice that including your PWD in your PATH variable is however a potential security risk.

Comment: You may have to set/change `JAVA_HOME` and `CLASSPATH` as well ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Yup, u r right!  But I hope the OP gets the drift...

Comment: Maybe a slightly naïve question, but why do I need to set add pwd to the PATH?

Comment: @ChrisW `pwd` is your current directory, and `PATH` is the list of directories where executables are searched for. By putting pwd on top of PATH, you are saying: whenever I issue a command, see whether there is a **local** version, and, if there is, let this take precedence over globally defined alternatives.